# unix: copy files across two directories without overwriting existing

Tags: unix

I have 2 folders , A and B.  they are similar, but there are some files in A that are not present in B. what's the best way to copy only the new files in A into B, without changing the existing files in B?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `--update` option to `rsync`:

```
cd A
rsync -a --update . ../B/
```

And you can do something similar using tar's `--skip-old-files` option:

```
cd A
tar -cf- . | tar -C ../B -xv --skip-old-files -f-
```

Comment: With rsync you'd want `--ignore-existing` if you don't want to replace the files that have the same names but different contents.

Comment: This is a pretty old question and answer, but still: I think the cpio example above is wrong. In my tests, cpio would always overwrite an older existing file in B with a newer version in A. This is not what the OP was asking for. And I don't see a way around it in the cpio manual.

Comment: @Carsten, you're right!  I replaced it with a `tar` example.

Answer (score 1):

`cp` with `-n`.

Comment: This is there on my Ubuntu system, but `man cp` on my Centos 5.5 system seems to be missing it.